# Can't assign onpaste event to SimpleTextEditor

Tags: javascript, text, editor

I have installed the SimpleTextEditor (http://www.gosu.pl/steditor/) because it's light and easy to modify. Created all wanted extra modules but have confronted and unfortunate incident - I can't catch the onpaste event for this editor to make users paste plain text only when they copy it from applications like Microsoft Word or broswers. I tried

```
ste.onpaste=function(){}
ste.document.onpaste
ste.document.body.onpaste
```

I even tried to do it from the insider functions - in this.init()

```
this.frame.document.onpaste=function(){};
this.frame.document.body.onpaste=function(){};
this.frame.onpaste=function(){};
this.onpaste=function(){};
```

neither of those work. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a generic solution try jquery

```
jQuery('#elementId').bind('paste', function(e){ alert('Someone pasted something!') })
```